# Having a uncaught error axioserror whenever try to open admin dashboard

Tags: reactjs, axios, e-commerce, mern, react-fullstack

ERROR
Request failed with status code 404
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404
at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:167104:12)
at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:165790:66)

I am having this error in e commerce mern project WHENEVER I AM trying to open admin dashboard. where is the actual problem im not getting it

"Encountered two children with the same key, `4`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version."

Answer (score 0):

In React, when rendering an array of elements or compoments using map() function, each item should have a unique key prop.
This helps React efficiently update and reorder the list when changes occur.

To fix this issue, you need to ensure that every child element or component generated by the map() function has a unique key.
The key could be an identifier from your data, such as an ID or index(but index is not good decision) just like this :

```
{
  data.map((item) => (
     <ItemComponent key={item.id}/>
 ))
}
```

Make sure the `key` prop is set to a value that is unique for each item within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`Encountered two children with the same key` This is a common React issue. Check all of our iterators on that page and look at what you are passing for a `key` value to the children.  Each group of keys **MUST** be unique.

You are using the value of `4` as the key for a group more than once.
Check the that what you are iterating over does not have duplicates. If so find a way to augment your key to be unique.

A good resource is the [React Docs](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#rules-of-keys) on this.

Answer (score -1):

he error message you provided suggests two separate issues. Let's address them individually:

1. Error 404: This error typically indicates that the requested resource or page was not found on the server. It seems that when you try to open the admin dashboard in your MERN (MongoDB, Express.js, React.js, Node.js) e-commerce project, the server is unable to locate the necessary files or endpoints associated with the dashboard. To troubleshoot this issue, you can take the following steps:

   - Verify the URL or route you are using to access the admin dashboard.
   - Ensure that the server-side code is properly configured to handle requests related to the admin dashboard.
   - Check if the necessary files and dependencies for the admin dashboard are correctly installed and accessible.
   - Verify the server logs for any additional error messages or clues regarding the 404 error.
2. Non-unique keys error: This warning indicates that you have provided multiple components with the same key prop in a list of components. Each key should be unique within the list to ensure proper component identification and rendering. To resolve this issue, you need to identify the component or components that are causing the warning and assign unique key values to them. Look for the key prop in the code and ensure that each key value is unique within its parent component.

Here are some steps to resolve the non-unique keys issue:

- Examine the code associated with the admin dashboard or any other components mentioned in the error message.
- Check for the usage of the key prop within the components and ensure that each key value is unique.
- If necessary, you can use a unique identifier from your data source (e.g., database ID) or generate unique keys programmatically.
- Make sure the keys are consistent across updates to avoid unnecessary re-rendering issues.

By addressing these two issues, you should be able to resolve the error you're encountering in your MERN e-commerce project. If you need further assistance, please provide more specific details or code snippets related to the problem areas, and I'll be glad to help you further.